# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 in a while loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, while-loop

I've been getting this exception and I've no idea how to go about fixing it:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

in the `while` loop. Here's my code:

```
public class NameSearch {
    static String[] names = new String[3];

    void populateStringArray() {
        names[0] = "Ben";
        names[1] = "Thor";
        names[2] = "Zoe";
        names[3] = "Kate";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pName;
        int max = 4;
        int current = 1;
        boolean found = false;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What player are you looking for?");
        pName = scan.next();
        while (found == false && current <= max) {
            if (names[current] == pName) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                current = current + 1;
            }
        }
        if (found == true) {
            System.out.println("Yes, they have a top score");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No, they do not have a top score");
        }
    }
}
```

The code is meant to ask the user to input a name and it will check to see if the name is in the array (in a nutshell).

My IDE (Eclipse) says that the error lies in the line `if (names[current] == pName){`.

Comment: [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have the condition `current <= max`. If `max` is `4` then that means `current` can equal `4` and there is no index `4` in the array. That's why the error comes from `names[current]`, you are trying to access index `4` and it doesn't exist. You should just use `<` instead of `<=` or have `max = 3` instead of `4`.

Side Notes:

- Because arrays start with an index `0` if `current` equals `1` when
  the loop begins it will never look at the first index in the array.
- When checking the value of a boolean as a condition, instead of doing `== true` or `== false`, you can just put the variable for `true` or add a `!` before for `false`. So in this case instead of `while(found == false` you can do `while(!found`.
- When incrementing an `int`, instead of `current = current + 1`, the common practice is to use `current++` when incrementing by 1 or `+=` when incrementing by more than 1 (for example `current +=2` would increment `current` by 2).

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within this condition: `found == false && current<= max` - Sidenote: `found == false` can be simplified to `!false` and will still evaluate to the same result. `current<=max` allows the loop to run with `current == max` and `max` is defined as 4. Thus you get a read at `names[4]` which is out-of-bounds. The simplest solution would be to change the condition from `current <= max` to `current<max`. And `current` is initialized as 1. Since arrays are 0-based in java this will cause the program to ommit the first name, which is at `names[0]`.

And another sidenote: using a constant as `max` is an extremely bug-prone method. Initialize `max` with `names.length` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
static String[] names = new String[3];
```

You are initializing an array with a *capacity* of three items, not a maximum index of 3. To get an array with 0, 1, 2, and 3, that's four items, so you'll need to initialize the array like so:

```
static String[] names = new String[4]; // (0-3)
```

Also, loops and arrays are zero-based, so you'll want to start with a `current` of 0 rather than 1 to loop over your array.
Additionally and finally, you'll want to switch the `<=` to `<` in your while loop, since we want it to only go up to 3.

Answer (score 2):

You are indexing your array elements in the loop between `1` and `4` (inclusive), when you need to be indexing them between `0` and `3` (inclusive).

Change `current` to start at `0`, and `max` to be `3` and you should be all good.

For perhaps an even better alternative, consider putting your list of names in a `HashSet` and not needing to iterate at all.  E.g.

```
Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
names.add("Ben");
names.add("Thor");
names.add("Zoe");
names.add("Kate");

if (names.contains(pName)) {
//...
```

If the ordering of the names is important, then you could use a `List` instead, which also has a `contains` method (just not generally as efficient as that in a `Map` implementation..  `O(n)` vs `O(1)` typically).  If the number of names in your list is small, or performance is not an issue, then it will not matter either way.

Comment: You might want to fix your code example ... ;P (it can't compile in the current state)

Comment: @Tom You mean because it refers to `pName` or because the `if` is not completed?  The intention was not for the code to compile on its own, just to be a short snippet to illustrate what changes to make to the original code to use a better solution than loop iteration for checking the player name.

Comment: No, I meant the _everyone_ uses `"` for String literals (and `'` for chars), so you should do that, too ;P.

Comment: @Tom lol, good point, will fix it, thanks!  I have been writing too much JavaScript lately and our style guide for JS demands single quotes for strings (to my everlasting frustration).

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop needs fixing: When your `current` is equal to `max`, it will still check for `name[4]` which doesnot exist.

In Addition, `==` is not the best way to compare 2 `Strings`. You must use `.equals()` method as it compares value of 2 `String` instead of comparing 2 Object reference. This is how your `while` loop should be fixed:

```
while (found == false && current< max){

    if (names[current].equals(pName)){
        found = true;
    } else {
        current = current + 1;
    }
}
```